# Increase sc_fifo_out size

Tags: size, fifo, systemc

Im declaring an sc_fifo as  `sc_fifo_out <int> PacketTx;` and Im trying to write 20 samples to this fifo using an `SC_THREAD`. I read the contents of the fifo in another `SC_THREAD`. The issue im having is that i need to write 20 values into the fifo before i read anything from the fifo, so im using an `sc_signal` to maintain this property.

Here's a simplified example:

Transmit.h

```
SC_MODULE(Transmit){
    sc_fifo_out<int> PacketTx;
    sc_inout<bool> busy;

    void Tx();
    SC_CTOR(Transmit){
      SC_THREAD(Tx){}
    }
};
```

Transmit.cpp

```
void Transmit::Tx(){
   int i=0;
   while(1){
      if(busy == 0){
         while(i!=20){
            busy = 1;  //Flag that specifies fifo is being used
            PacketTx.write(rand()%1+10)); //Random number between 1-10;
            i++;
         }
         busy = 0; //Done writing to fifo. Deassert flag
         i = 0;    //Reset counter
      }
      else{
         wait(rand()%1+10, SC_NS);
      }
   }
}
```

Receive.h

```
SC_MODULE(Receive){
    sc_fifo_in<int> PacketRx;
    sc_inout<bool> busy;

    void Rx();
    SC_CTOR(Receive){
      SC_THREAD(Rx){}
    }
};
```

Receive.cpp

```
void Receive::Rx(){
   int i=0;
   while(1){
      if(busy == 0){ //Check if fifo is being used
         while(i!=20){
            busy = 1;  
            PacketRx.read(); //Read 20 samples from fifo
            i++;
         }
         busy = 0; //Done reading; Deassert flag
         i = 0;    //Reset counter
      }
      else{
         wait(rand()%1+10, SC_NS); //Wait random NS duration and try again
      }
   }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Receive.h"
#include "Transmit.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* arg[]){

   //Signal/Port declarations
   sc_fifo<int> Packet;
   sc_signal<bool> busy;

   //Module Instantiation
   Receive r1("Receive");
   r1.busy(busy);
   r1.PacketRx(Packet);

   Transmit t1("Transmit);
   t1.busy(busy);
   t1.PacketTx(Packet);

   sc_start();

   return 0;
}
```

The issue i run into is that `sc_fifo_out` only lets me write 16 values to the fifo, however for my application I would like to increase it to 20, or potentially more. I tried to look around but didnt find anything on how to change the fifo size other than a forum post on [Accellera](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/15-sc_fifo-size/), but this this was only for `sc_fifo` and Im not sure how to adapt this to `sc_fifo_out`. I tried to do `sc_fifo_out<int> PacketTx(20);` in my PacketTx.h header but it was not syntactically valid.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the fifo channel, i.e. `Packet`. You can do the following:

```
sc_fifo<int> Packet(20);
```